# Joomla 1.5, modifying content module (article edition/creation)

Tags: php, file-upload, joomla, joomla1.5

I would like to ask You for a proper way of modifying Joomla's 1.5 article edition/creation page. What I need is additional field (e.g. under the editor) which takes a file input, upload the file to a certain folder (after this article was submitted/saved) and put its server path to database (db column already exist).

It is meant to be a title picture, I've already done displaying part, but I don't know how to let users choose and submit the picture themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of plugins available that will handle this for you. I would just install one of them. See the [extensions directory](http://extensions.joomla.org). Search for Attachments to get started.

Comment: Well, this is anywhere near the one I need. I'd rather code it than use some plugins.

Comment: I don't understand, but specifically the one called attachments I think will do what you need.

Comment: Well... I want to hard-code it, I don't want to use any external plugins. I just need to know WHERE I should begin with coding it.

Comment: Well you would want to write your own plugin then. That's how Joomla works. Especially 1.5 you don't even have a simple way to add a field but you can add an editor-xtd button.